# Aggregated search on a "keyword" field on an Elasticsearch index

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an index on Elasticsearch on which I would like to perform an aggregation on a field of type `text` which is treated as a categorical field.

In the index mappings I've defined that field to be treated as a `keyword` so I don't have to use `fielddata=true` as explained in the documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html

When performing this HTTP GET query I am not getting the aggregated results, Elasticsearch returns the whole index instead (all the full documents):

```
GET my_stuff_index/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "constant_score" : {
      "filter" : {
        "exists" : { "field" : "xyz.keyword" }
      }
    }
  },
    "aggs": {
        "my_avg_ratings_report": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "xyz.keyword"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

How can I treat that `xyz` field as categorical and use it in an aggregation?

To generate a minimum working example with some documents in a dummy index I've used the following python script where the index mapping is also defined:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers

my_docs = [
    {"xyz": "foo", "description": "bla bla bla"},
    {"xyz": "foo", "description": "bla bla bla xyz"},
    {"xyz": "bar", "description": "bla bla bla abc"},
    {"xyz": "bar", "description": "bla bla bla 123"},
    {"xyz": "baz", "description": "bla bla bla 456"},
    {"xyz": "qux", "description": "bla bla bla 789"},
]

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

index_mapping = '''
{
  "mappings":{
    "my_stuff_type":{
      "properties":{
          "xyz": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}'''

es.indices.create(index='my_stuff_index', ignore=400, body=index_mapping)

helpers.bulk(es, my_docs, index='my_stuff_index', doc_type='my_stuff_type')
```

Comment: can you write the output returned by your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do aggregation on `xyz.keyword` field even without any special mapping. If you are not interested in search hits just add `"size": 0` property on the top level of your query.